# Should someone be fired over the weekend or on Monday?

Tags: management

After discussing it with me, the CEO of my company decided to let go a contractor over the weekend. The office manager suggested we do the firing on Monday morning as soon as he gets in. Is this proper procedure? Or, should we let him know now by phone/email and not have him come in when we know we're going to let him go?

Also, the office manager needs to be present for the dismissal, but I usually get in before everyone else, and then the contractor, and then the office manager. It all seems very disingenuous for me to act normal to the contractor (who is also my friend) for the 1-2 hours until the office manager comes in.

Comment: Will the person be sent home directly afterwards? You should consider firing them an hour or two before the end of their shift to thwart questions asked. They may be emotional afterwards, and it'd be better if it was at the end of the day / they get to go home rather than making them endure the day.

Comment: Even with firing (or letting go) a contractor, there may be paperwork and even some kind of equipment handover (laptop, company provided phone, whatever). It's easier to get this done if the person being fired has come to the office rather than emailing them over the weekend and asking them to drop their things at the office the next week.

Comment: Important decisions and changes (which "getting fired" certainly is) should really be done in person. I'd rather travel to work just to hear I'm getting fired than receiving an email in my weekend saying the same.

Answer (score 12):

> The office manager suggested we do the firing on Monday morning as
>   soon as he gets in. Is this proper procedure?

I'm not sure what you mean by "proper" here, but it seems perfectly reasonable to me for handling a contractor dismissal (it might be different if this were an employee rather than a contractor). If the standard in your office is that the office manger must be present, this seems "proper" to me.

> It all seems very disingenuous for me to act normal to the contractor
>   (who is also my friend) for the 1-2 hours until the office manager
>   comes in.

So either make yourself scarce for a few hours or come in late that morning.

These things happen. Sometimes they are awkward. Your friend will understand and not blame you.